# View files via links in Zend MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, hyperlink, href, zend-framework

In my app I have a module named "client".  I wish to create a sub directory "statements" and below that "accounts" then "account_123" and within this directory the pdfs representing statements for clint 123.
Structure client then statements then accounts then acount_XXX and the pdf files.

**The problem**

```
<a href=What_is_the_url_for">statement_1.pdf</a>?
```

Being MVC I am making little progess.

I moved the structure to public and it almost wotk except I could not retrieve dynamically the hostname i.r. www.hostnam.com/client/statement....

I know this is a security issue so I have moved the directory back yo below the client module.

Any help will be appreciayed.

TIA  Ephraim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't place a direct link to a file placed under 'application' director (because of security issues as you already wrote), so one of possible solution is to make an action which read the content of a file and return it in a response object.

When user click a link to this action user get a window to open/save provided file.

Example:

```
public function exampleAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    /* ... */

    $file = "FILENAME WITH_PATH";
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Description', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . FILENAME, true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', FILETYPE, true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file), true);                    
    $response->setBody(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

I put in above code some constants because its values depends on your application.

Comment: Can I hide the Open/Save dialog box? i.e. just show the file as I can in straight php non-MVC applications?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want to achieve - could you explain? Do you want to display the content of pdf file in web page? I thought that you want to create a link to file that could be downloaded by the user.

Comment: The former is correct.  Firefox opens a dialog offering me the choice of Open or save.  I would prefer no dialog and the pdf open in Acrobat without the dialog.  Something to do with content type I tried 'application/pdf' but it did not work. Amy ideas TIA.

Comment: I think, that issue depends on local program settings. When you install Acrobat Reader it asks one, whether open PDF file automatically in web browser.